# Sequelize "unique: true" making same unique key two times with different keyname

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

**Test1:** Adding "unique: true" in email attribute.

**Test2:** Adding "unique: {args: true, msg: "xxxxxx"}" in email attribute.

**Using Sequelize: 4.7.5 & MySQL: 5.7.19**

I'm expecting there will be one index for both the test cases.

But I'm getting **two indexes** for the Test1. Both indexes are having **same column** but **different keyname**.

Is it a bug or I'm doing anything wrong?

**Try the following model defs.**

```
Test1 = {
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
},

emailId: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
        isEmail: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Invalid email id.'
        }
    }
}
}


Test2 = {
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
},

emailId: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: {
        args: true,
        msg: 'This email id is already registered.'
    },
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
        isEmail: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Invalid email id.'
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use string instead boolean.**

I found my answer here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6134

[Normal index with string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Mnw.png)

Comment: Arrr!!!! I missed the listing in issue tracker. So I was right, its a bug.